# is it posible to run WS IIS on UNIX?

Tags: c#

is it posible to run my WebService in IIS on UNIX ?
if no, so what can i do ?

thank's for any help

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) and mod_mono for Apache. It *should* work out-of-the-box. There's no chance, as far as I know, to run IIS under *nix, at least for licensing reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I must add that some proprietary classes may not be available. Only .NET classes that are defined by ECMA, and whatever the Mono project implemented are available.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run IIS on UNIX. What you can do is run it on Windows where it belongs.

If this is a personal project then, by all means, trust it to Mono if you wish. I'm unconvinced that Mono is ready for prime-time and far too many Microsoft "partners" have found themselves stranded once they became good enough to compete with the Microsoft core products.

I'm of the personal opinion (and it's only opinion so don't bother arguing with me) that Mono will either remain a less-than-adequately-supported backwater or be destroyed altogether if it starts to become too successful.

But if it's anything of importance, you need to run it in a supported configuration. That means no Mono, no UNIX.

Otherwise, when you call Microsoft for help, they get to laugh at you mercilessly :-).